# Webpack polyfills for React application using MQTT

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mqtt, create-react-app, hivemq

I created a new project using a typescript template using `create-react-app`. I want my react app to subscribe to MQTT Broker. That's why I used the typescript `mqtt` library. I followed the documentation, but after starting my react app I become the following problem:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/mqtt/lib/connect/index.js 5:12-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/Users/test/Code/mqtt-subscriber/node_modules/mqtt/lib/connect'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
```

The used versions are:

```
    "mqtt": "^4.3.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
```

Do you have any ideas on how to resolve the problem? I don't have a webpack configuration file.

If I install the `url` package I get other error:

```
Buffer is not defined 'url'5:12-26 Module not found
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [this github issue](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/1558) - try importing from `dist`:

```
import mqtt from "mqtt/dist/mqtt";
```

or using [mqtt-precompiled](https://www.npmjs.com/package/precompiled-mqtt)

Answer (score 0):

Heavily borrowing from @Taxel's answer, you have to use:

```
import * as mqtt from 'mqtt/dist/mqtt.min';
```

As mentioned by the maintainers of the library [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt?activeTab=readme#webpack)